# «В ней сердце долго ли страдало, иль скоро слёз прошла пора?» Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, ссп

Почему здесь стоит запятая? Ведь это ССП, части которого объединены вопросительной интонацией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что пишет Розенталь:

> **Примечания:** 1. В сложносочиненном предложении сочетание *ли…или* рассматривается как повторяющийся союз (в отличие от простого предложения с однородными членами, в котором *ли…или* не образуют повторяющегося союза, вследствие чего запятая перед или не ставится): *Во сне **ль** всё это снится мне, **или** гляжу я в самом деле, на что при этой же луне с тобой живые мы глядели?* (Тютч.); *Серьёзно **ли** в ней гнездилось это намерение, **или** она только шутки шутила* (С.‑Щ.); *Жалобный **ли** тон Авдотьи подействовал на Буянова, **или** сведения о количестве поросят произвели на него впечатление, но через минуту он дал свет* (Ник.).

Думаю, что это наше правило, так как ***ли... или*** = ***ли... иль*** = ***ль... или***. При повторяющемся союзе вопросительная интонация уже не спасает: запятую надо ставить.

[Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

Comment: Ага, спасибо! У меня было подозрение насчёт частицы 'ли', но не нашёл точного правила.

Comment: Ага, пожалуйста! Рада, что точное правило нашлось. Жаль, правда, что ответ бесполезный.