# Почему правило о союзе ЛИ...ИЛИ разное для однородных членов и сложного предложения?

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение, или

Как известно из правил Розенталя, этот союз относится к одиночным союзам в предложении с однородными членами,  но становится повторяющимся в сложном предложении (ССП и СПП).

Решение выглядит **формальным,** так что хочется спросить –  а почему?

Для лучшего понимания проблемы я приведу пример из недавно заданного вопроса и сравню два варианта. [https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/469825/В-ней-сердце-долго-ли-страдало-иль-скоро-слёз-прошла-пора-почему-здесь-зап](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/469825/%D0%92-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF)

(1)  *В ней сердце долго **ли** страдало, **иль** скоро слёз прошла пора?*

(2) *В ней сердце долго **еще** страдало  **иль** скоро слёз прошла пора?*

**И вопрос:** Во втором предложении вы не поставите запятую?

Если нет, то правило действительно сложно объяснить – ведь предложения очень похожи по своей структуре.

А каково ваше решение и ваше мнение?

Comment: Вы о чём спрашиваете? О формальности постановки/непостановки запятой или о формальности классификации?

Comment: Я спрашиваю:  (1) почему такой разный подход к союзу ЛИ...ИЛИ для однородных членов и сложного предложения?  (2) Что меняет, что дает нам  присутствие частицы ЛИ в сложном предложении?  Вот я заменило ее другим словом и теперь запятая не ставится? А я бы в обоих случаях поставила запятую, структура и интонация предложений совершенно одинаковая. Значит, дело не в самой частице, а в той структуре, с которой она связана. Вот в чем мне видится причина. И тогда особое отношение к ЛИ...ИЛИ становится понятным, не кажется формальным.

Comment: Но если не задавать такого вопроса, если ничего не объяснять и не стараться понять, то  очень скоро может состояться нежелательная для нашей культуры реформа письма, а нашу уникальную письменность некому будет защитить. Как там у Окуджавы:  «Каждый пишет, как он слышит, Каждый слышит, как он дышит, Как он дышит, так и пишет…». Наша письменная речь – это запись устной речи, хотя об этом не принято говорить. А это мало кто понимает, а скоро не будет понимать никто.

Comment: *почему такой разный подход к союзу ЛИ...ИЛИ для однородных членов и сложного предложения?* — какой подход? Вы про называние союза одиночным/повторяющимся? Или про пунктуационные отличия в простом и сложном предложениях? Честно говоря, ваша замена ужасна. "Ещё" там вообще не подходит. Подходит "уже".

Comment: Что там подходит, мне без разницы, я просто взяла короткое слово, чтобы не менять структуру. А два ваших вопроса из вашего комментария - это один и тот же вопрос. Если союз считается то одиночным, то повторяющимся, то правила для них различны.  Так вы можете на него ответить, есть версия?

Comment: Но запятая в сложном предложении связана с двумя грамматическими основами, а не с тем, какой там союз. Розенталь: Союзы *ли... или* в сложносочиненном предложении считаются повторяющимися, и перед вторым из них ставится запятая (**поскольку она ставится перед *или* и без предшествующего *ли***), в отличие от предложений с однородными членами, соединенными союзами *ли... или*, в которых запятая перед *или* не ставится. По всей видимости, условно считаются, из-за наличия запятой.

Comment: Частицу ЛИ можно включать или не включать в состав союза. Для однородных членов мы ее не включаем (у нас только ИЛИ - одиночный союз), а в сложном предложении включаем (у нас ЛИ...ИЛИ - повторяющийся союз).  Я правильно это понимаю?

Comment: Нет. Выше ж написано: в отличие от предложений с однородными членами, соединенными **союзами
*ли... или***. Там их не считают повторяющимися из-за отсутствия запятой, но их всё так же два.

Comment: А мне кажется, что все взаимосвязано. Но надо еще раз внимательно все прочитать. Отложим пока обсуждение. Кстати, в СПП с однородными придаточными он тоже считается повторяющимся.

Comment: Спасибо, я подумаю над темой в целом.

Comment: Нет, удалённый комментарий — ерунда, не учитывайте его, если прочитали, там перепутал.

Comment: Ладно, oleedd, я думаю, вместе разберемся.  Тема, действительно, путаная, а сейчас, до 19 января, лучше не напрягаться :)  Спасибо еще раз за общение, закрою пока сессию, а то я кому-то здесь мешаю...

Answer (score 1):

Формальное, конечно. Но в русском языке имеется рад формальных правил, и не вижу в этом ничего плохого.

Например, максимально формально, как по мне, правило о постановке запятой перед "если", если этот союз одиночный, и непостановке, если имеется продолжение "то".

- "И, если ты не передумаешь, я тебя засужу".
- "И если ты не передумаешь, то я тебя засужу".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133254/discussion-on-answer-by-nektoid---------).

Comment: @Sharon Почему союзы считаются повторяющимися в сложном предложении? Скорее всего, это условно из-за запятой, как уже говорил.

Comment: Я думаю, что надо учитывать разную грамматику и семантику двух вариантов, запятые только следствие, а истинная причина не раскрыта.

Comment: Не думаю, что эта истинная причина существует.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Обобщенная  информация  о союзе ЛИ…ИЛИ  у Розенталя**

В правилах Розенталя  (в теме о сложноподчиненных предложениях) дается **обобщенный сравнительный анализ** простых и сложных предложений с союзом ЛИ…ИЛИ.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139#pp139 (пункт 5, примечание).

В конце текста делается **вывод**:  «Следовательно, запятая перед ИЛИ не ставится, если ЛИ…ИЛИ соединяют **однородные** члены предложения, и ставится, если они соединяют **части сложного предложения**.

**Примечание**. Запятая также не ставится, если однородные члены входят в придаточное предложение  (тогда частица ЛИ   используется   вместо подчинительного союза):
Он не знал, вернуться ЛИ на прежнее место ИЛИ оставаться здесь.
Мы не знали, туда ЛИ мы идём ИЛИ всё дальше уходим от истинного пути.

**2. На чем основано такое правило**

Правило несложно в использовании, но выглядит формальным – ведь причину своего решения Розенталь не указывает. Но в действительности **такая причина существует** – этот вывод можно сделать, если ознакомиться с дополнительными материалами.

**2. О союзе ЛИ... ИЛИ**

Из словаря: **Союз ЛИ... ЛИ и ЛИ... ИЛИ.**  Присоединяет предложения или члены предложения, по значению исключающие или заменяющие друг друга, при указании на возможность или необходимость выбора между ними. *В городе **ли**, в селе **ли** надо честно трудиться. Быстро **ли**, медленно **ли**, но работу надо делать*. Паду **ли** я, стрелой пронзённый, **Иль** мимо пролетит она.*

В Грамматике указаны следующие сведения  о  союзе  ЛИ…ИЛИ.
[http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы#515](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#515)

Пункт 5.1.5. **Союзы ЛИ... ЛИ и ЛИ... ИЛИ** выражают равноценность компонентов при выборе,  причем обычно говорящий сам не знает, какой из возможных компонентов присутствует.

Повторяющийся союз ЛИ... ИЛИ  **следует отличать** от сочетания вопросительной частицы ЛИ с одиночным разделительным союзом ИЛИ.

**3. Из этой информации и приведенных примеров можно сделать выводы:**

(1) повторяющийся союз ЛИ…ЛИ используется **для однородных членов**:  В городе ли, в селе ли надо честно трудиться.

(2) повторяющийся  союз ЛИ…ИЛИ используется **в сложных предложениях**, причем каждая часть союза относится к своей предикативной основе: Паду ли я, стрелой пронзённый, Иль мимо пролетит она?

(3) Союз ЛИ…ИЛИ в случае однородных членов делится на усилительную вопросительную **частицу ЛИ**, которая относится ко всему предложению, и **одиночный разделительный союз ИЛИ**: А случались ли когда-нибудь накладки или даже  казусы во время вашего выступления?

Таким образом,  **разная классификация** союза ЛИ…ИЛИ  (одиночный или повторяющийся) определяется **разной структурой предложений**, в которых они могут использоваться.

4. **Сравним применение ЛИ…ИЛИ на примерах:**

Однородные члены: *Видит ли он это или не видит?  Было ли это во сне или наяву?* Запятая не ставится.

Сложное предложение: *Видит ли он это,  или что-то ему мешает?  Был ли это сон,  или всё произошло на самом деле?* Запятая ставится.

5. **Если убрать частицу ЛИ**:

Однородные члены: *Видит  он это или не видит?  Было это во сне  или наяву?* В этом случае ничего не меняется.

Сложное предложение: *Видит  он это или что-то ему мешает?  Был это сон  или всё произошло на самом деле?*  Вопросительная интонация объединяет два предложения в случае одиночного союза ИЛИ, запятая не ставится.

Comment: В этом примере Грамоты ЛИ не относится ко всему предложению: *От света ли электричества или от волнения она слегка порозовела и кажется моложе.* Л. Андреев, Христиане. *А случались ли когда-нибудь накладки или даже казусы во время вашего выступления?* — а куда вы дели запятую? *Сложное предложение: Видит он это или что-то ему мешает? <...> запятая не ставится* — не согласен. Когда два простых предложения объединяются в одну фразу, в первом не делается никаких умышленных ударений. Здесь же по смыслу нужно сделать ударение на "видит", что нарушает единство фразы.

Comment: (1) Запятую я "выбросила" как ненужную и использовала оформление по Розенталю.  Хотела даже написать об этом, но потом передумала.  Может, там союз И присоединительный. (2) Видит он это или что-то ему мешает? И без ударения хорошо читается. (3) От света ли электричества или от волнения...  Частицу ЛИ можно убрать, она усилительная, поэтому для грамматики необязательная.

Comment: 1. Не помешало бы. Там какой-то перелом конструкции, и присоединение имеется. 2. Если как бы читать без ударений, они автоматически становятся такими: *Видит он Это или что-то ему мешАет?* Так? Оно не звучит. 3. Но это со страницы про *ли... или*: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_392

Comment: Не звучит? Тогда поставьте запятую и скажите, что у вас авторская пунктуация.  А Грамота написала: не образует двойного союза. Вот не образует – и всё тут!

Comment: Не надо "авторской пунктуации" (понимаете, зачем здесь кавычки?), надо просто поменять порядок слов: *Он это видит или что-то ему мешает?* Хотя здесь лучше с присоединительной интонацией (с паузой). Грамота повторяет Розенталя и Лопатина. Они с большой осторожностью добавляют что-то от себя.

Comment: Ваше предложение  сложнее прочесть в одну фразу, а мой вариант читается плавно.  "Он это" – плохая фонетическая сочетаемость, это тоже надо учитывать, а не только ударения.

Comment: Почему плохая? Гласная после согласной. Ваш вариант нелогичен: *Видит он [именно] это или что-то ему мешает?* Во втором вопросе нет логики.

Comment: Есть там логика, смотрите внимательнее. У меня точно была :))

Comment: Ну и в чём она?

Comment: Сначала скажите, в чем ее отсутствие. Завтра договорим, ага?

Comment: Что за "ага" постоянно? Как-то тупо. *Видит он это (а не другое) или что-то ему мешает?* Вопросы не связаны. Если он видит другое (а не "это"), то ему ничего не мешает ("или" не к месту).

Comment: У вас логика ограничена одним вариантом (вашим), а здесь  местоимение "это" – то, что видят другие.

Comment: Тогда ударение надо на "видит", тогда звучит по-русски.